# 2d array matrix not printing properly

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Matrix is not printing properly, Can anyone tell me where I went wrong??

```
int i , j;
       int n =0 , m =0;
       int p =0 , q =0;
       int matrix1[n][m];
       int matrix2[p][q];

       printf("ENTER THE NUMBER OF ROWS AND COLUMNS IN 1st MATRIX\n");
       scanf ("%d%d",&n,&m);

       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            for (j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
               printf ("ENTER THE matrix1[%d][%d]:  ",i,j);
               scanf ("%d",&matrix1[i][j]);

            }
```

I believe this is where the problem is.

```
      for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
          for (j=0;j<m;j++)
          {
             printf ("%d ",matrix1[i][j]);

          }
        printf ("\n");
      }
```

Comment: `int matrix1[n][m];
       int matrix2[p][q];` ,Size 0, After you enter the size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want memory to store objects whose size is known only during runtime, I would suggest you to allocate it as required, use the following code

```
   int i, j;
   int n, m;
   int **matrix;

   printf("ENTER THE NUMBER OF ROWS AND COLUMNS IN 1st MATRIX\n");
   scanf ("%d%d",&n,&m);

   matrix = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n);
   if (!matrix) {/* no memory; handle it */}
   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
        for (j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
           printf ("ENTER THE matrix[%d][%d]:  ",i,j);
           scanf ("%d",&matrix[i][j]);

        }
```

Don't forget to free your memory

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  free(matrix[i]);
free(matrix);
```